# How can I pivot data based on Month and year wise client Report

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to retrieve data based on Month of every year. It will get but sorting is not correct.

```
SELECT Client,DispacthDate,Models,Model1,Model2,Model3
FROM  (
        SELECT  Client
                ,Concat(year(Audit_Date),' ',datename(month,Audit_Date)) as DispatchDate
                ,Models
                ,Count(Models) 'Units'
        FROM dbo.ABC
        GROUP BY Client,Concat(year(Audit_Date),' ',datename(month,Audit_Date)),Models
      ) abcd
PIVOT(SUM(Units) FOR Models IN (Model1,Model2,Model3)) as P
ORDER BY Client,DispatchDate
```

I'll get result set like this:

```
 
Client  DispatchDate    Model1  Model2  Model3
Client1 2017 December   0   0   0
Client1 2017 November   25  0   0
Client1 2018 January    21  0   0
Client1 2018 March       9  0   0
Client2 2017 December    8  0   0
Client2 2018 April       5  0   0
Client2 2018 August      0  0   0
Client2 2018 July        0  0   0
Client2 2018 March       0  0   0
Client3 2017 December    4  0   0
Client3 2017 November   687 0   0
Client3 2018 April       8  0   0
Client3 2018 January     0  0   0
```

But Required Data Like:

```
Client  DispatchDate    Model1  Model2  Model3
Client1 2018 January    21  0   0
Client1 2018 March       9  0   0
Client1 2017 November   25  0   0
Client1 2017 December   0   0   0
Client2 2018 March      0   0   0
Client2 2018 April      5   0   0
Client2 2018 July       0   0   0
Client2 2018 August     0   0   0
Client2 2017 December   8   0   0
Client3 2018 January    0   0   0
Client3 2018 April      8   0   0
Client3 2017 November   687 0   0
Client3 2017 December   4   0   0
```

Please Any one suggest me for my query.

Comment: Try: `ORDER BY Client, DispatchDate DESC`

Comment: Yes, you can get this result with ORDER BY Client, DispatchDate DESC

Comment: months are not ordering with ORDER BY Client, DispatchDate DESC

Comment: The current result that you posted does not matches with the query. In the result you show the `DispatchDate` as `2017 December`. But if based on the query that you posted it should be `2017 12` . Please update your question accordingly

Comment: sorry i just forgot a function to place. Now u can try @Squirrel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding,

```
SELECT Client,DispacthDate,Models,Model1,Model2,Model3
FROM  (
        SELECT  Client
                ,Concat(year(Audit_Date),' ',datename(month,Audit_Date)) as DispatchDate
                ,Models
                ,Count(Models) 'Units'
        FROM dbo.ABC
        GROUP BY Client,Concat(year(Audit_Date),' ',datename(month,Audit_Date)),Models
      ) abcd
PIVOT(SUM(Units) FOR Models IN (Model1,Model2,Model3)) as P
ORDER BY Client,
, DATEPART (YYYY, convert(date, DispacthDate)) desc  -- here query has been changed.
, DATEPART (MM, convert(date, DispacthDate))  -- here query has been changed.
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't convert the DispatchDate to string in the inner query. Keep it in date or datetime type. And then convert it at the outer query

```
SELECT Client,
       DATENAME(YEAR, Audit_Date) + ' ' + DATENAME(MONTH, Audit_Date) AS DispatchDate,  
       Models, Model1, Model2, Model3
FROM  (
        SELECT  Client
                ,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, Audit_Date), 0) as Audit_Date
                ,Models
                ,Count(Models) AS Units
        FROM    dbo.ABC
        GROUP BY Client, 
                 DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, Audit_Date), 0), month(Audit_Date)),
                 Models
      ) abcd
PIVOT(SUM(Units) FOR Models IN (Model1,Model2,Model3)) as P
ORDER BY Client, Audit_Date
```

Comment: by this query, I'm not able to get Month wise grouping

Comment: yes. it is `DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, Audit_Date), 0)` will gives you the first day of the month